# Pointing dojo registry / widget references to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

How can I target an iframe in the below? I've tried incorporating dojo/request/iframe with no luck. Having zero experience in using dojo, I would appreciate any help.

```
require(["dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(CheckBox, registry, Button) {

  var markCheckAll = function() {
    registry.toArray().forEach(function(widget) {
      if (widget.type === 'checkbox'){
        widget.set('checked', true);
      }
    });
  };
  markCheckAll();

});
```

Comment: do you want to check all checkbox that ara in an Iframe ?

Comment: No. I am trying to use the above to find all of the checkboxes then I will just check against widget.id to make sure it is the one I want.

Comment: could you illustrate an example of how your html is (iframe + main code), what want you reach